# React Native TextInput not scroll in ScrollView

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, scrollview, react-native-textinput

I write a code like this:

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
    <ScrollView style={{flex:1, backgroundColor='#ffffff'}}>
        <TextInput style={styles.inputText} 
                   value={this.state.mail}
                   placeholder="Email"
                   onChangeText={(text)=>this.setState.(mail:text)}/>
        <TextInput style={styles.inputText} 
                   value={this.state.fName}
                   placeholder="First name"
                   onChangeText={(text)=>this.setState.(fName:text)}/>
        <TextInput style={styles.inputText} 
                   value={this.state.sName}
                   placeholder="Second name"
                   onChangeText={(text)=>this.setState.(sName:text)}/>
    </ScrollView>
</View>
```

but when i drag start in TextInput does not scroll!
i drag like this picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edDFi.png)
but not scroll...

Comment: Try by adding 3 more TextInput

Comment: Remove the flex:1 from scrollview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved. I just add this props to TextInput Components:

```
multiline={true}
numberOfLines={1}
```